# Optical Character Recognisation for android

Tags: android

HI am working on OCR(Optical Character Recognization) i got a sample project from github.For this project am using tess-test library project and the project builds and executes successfully but whenever the TessBaseAPI is called the app stopped unfortunately..and it shows that the "liblapt.so" couldnot found.

```
07-14 17:12:06.367: V/SimpleAndroidOCR.java(29415): Starting Camera app
07-14 17:12:06.888: D/OpenGLRenderer(29415): endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb7eba250 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb7eb97c0
07-14 17:12:08.710: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29415): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
07-14 17:12:19.148: I/SimpleAndroidOCR.java(29415): resultCode: -1
07-14 17:12:19.732: V/SimpleAndroidOCR.java(29415): Orient: 0
07-14 17:12:19.733: V/SimpleAndroidOCR.java(29415): Rotation: 0
07-14 17:12:19.744: V/SimpleAndroidOCR.java(29415): Before baseApi
07-14 17:12:19.747: D/AndroidRuntime(29415): Shutting down VM
07-14 17:12:19.766: I/art(29415): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 149(10KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(16KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 10MB/10MB, paused 16.465ms total 31.934ms
07-14 17:12:19.766: E/AndroidRuntime(29415): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 17:12:19.766: E/AndroidRuntime(29415): Process: com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple, PID: 29415
07-14 17:12:19.766: E/AndroidRuntime(29415): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "liblept.so"
07-14 17:12:19.766: E/AndroidRuntime(29415):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
07-14 17:12:19.766: E/AndroidRuntime(29415):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:989)
07-14 17:12:19.766: E/AndroidRuntime(29415):    at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(TessBaseAPI.java:43)
07-14 17:12:19.766: E/AndroidRuntime(29415):    at com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.onPhotoTaken(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java:214)
07-14 17:12:19.766: E/AndroidRuntime(29415):    at com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.onActivityResult(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java:136)
07-14 17:12:19.766: E/AndroidRuntime(29415):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6161)
07-14 17:12:19.766: E/AndroidRuntime(29415):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3622)
07-14 17:12:19.766: E/AndroidRuntime(29415):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3669)
07-14 17:12:19.766: E/AndroidRuntime(29415):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:148)
07-14 17:12:19.766: E/AndroidRuntime(29415):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
07-14 17:12:19.766: E/AndroidRuntime(29415):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-14 17:12:19.766: E/AndroidRuntime(29415):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-14 17:12:19.766: E/AndroidRuntime(29415):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
07-14 17:12:19.766: E/AndroidRuntime(29415):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-14 17:12:19.766: E/AndroidRuntime(29415):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-14 17:12:19.766: E/AndroidRuntime(29415):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
07-14 17:12:19.766: E/AndroidRuntime(29415):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to build that library yourself.
Full code, instructions, and example at https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two

Comment: yes but I am getting the error "could not find the liblept.so".